# What effect would this most recent asteroid fly-by have had if it impacted?

Tags: asteroids

According to [this article](https://www.buzzfeednews.com/article/danvergano/nasa-emails-asteroid-2019-ok), an asteroid came dangerously close to the Earth.  The asteroid was roughly the size of a football field.

What would the result of this asteroid be if it had impacted square on the Earth's surface?  If negligible, at what mass does an asteroid impact become critical?

Comment: You can estimate [the size of the crater](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/195397/25301) from kinetic energy arguments & get a feel for the damage that way.

Comment: Some rough comparisons are given at the end of the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_OK ("2019 OK" is the provisional designation of the asteroid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asteroid 2019 OK is about the size of a football field, and was travelling about 54,379 miles per hour, with closest approach of about 44,300 miles. If it would have hit Earth it would have been a city killer, with about 30 times the energy of the Hiroshima bomb.

Comment: Where do you get 30 times from? Seems to me, assuming a mass of 10^9 kg, it would be more like 10000 times.

Comment: @Ben51: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_OK#Potential_impact_effects and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPDBpThe8Ns at about 1:40