# Calculating collapse factor in the crater equation

Tags: planets, meteors

In the Crater Equation 
$$
D=0.07C_f\left(\frac{g_e}{g}\right)^{1/6}\left(E \frac{\rho_a}{\rho_t}\right)^{1/3.4}
$$
where $\rho_a$ is the density of the impactor, $\rho_t$ that of the object, $g_e$ Earth's gravitational acceleration, $g$ the gravitational acceleration of the object, and $C_f$ the collapse factor.

In this equation, how is the $C_F$ calculated?

Comment: First result on google: http://palaeo.gly.bris.ac.uk/communication/brana/equation.html

Comment: Also, related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195152/crater-equation

Comment: First result on google is the link to the equation, without providing any explanation to my answer. And the stackexachange link doesn't provide much clarity on the topic.

Comment: From what I googled afterwards, it seems that ${C}_{F}$ isn't calculated, it's experimentally deduced. The second link just provides another viewpoint on the matter.

Comment: However in [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195336/proportionality-constant-in-crater-equations?newreg=56d8acd08eb3421181f74761e6a63526) link, the answer does appear to have an calculated answer.

Comment: Well, then you have an answer :)